# Removing SEO Tags from a Wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress-theming

I am having a problem removing two lines of code in a php file. When I remove them I get a white screen on options.php and post.php I think it is a simple code error, but I am not having any success in figuring it out. The code I am starting with is

```
$this->pagetitle=sprintf($format,$title);
        if ($this->get( 'seo','keywords' )!=''&&$keywords!='')$keywords.=",";
        if ($this->get( 'seo','description' )!=''&&$descr!='')$descr.=" ";
        if (($descrln=200-iconv_strlen($descr, "utf-8"))>=(strpos($this->get( 'seo', 'description' ),' ')))
            $descr.=iconv_substr($this->get( 'seo', 'description' ), 0, $descrln, 'utf-8' );
        if ( $echo ) {
            echo "<title>".sprintf($format,$title)."</title>\r\n";
            echo '<meta name="Description" content="'.preg_replace('/[\'\"]/', '',$descr)."\" />\r\n";
            echo '<meta name="Keywords" content="'.$keywords.$this->get( 'seo', 'keywords' )."\" />\r\n";
        } else {
            return sprintf($format,$title);
        }
    }

}
```

The lines I am removing are

```
echo '<meta name="Description" content="'.preg_replace('/[\'\"]/', '',$descr)."\" />\r\n";
            echo '<meta name="Keywords" content="'.$keywords.$this->get( 'seo', 'keywords' )."\" />\r\n";
```

The result that is creating the issue is

```
$this->pagetitle=sprintf($format,$title);
        if ($this->get( 'seo','keywords' )!=''&&$keywords!='')$keywords.=",";
        if ($this->get( 'seo','description' )!=''&&$descr!='')$descr.=" ";
        if (($descrln=200-iconv_strlen($descr, "utf-8"))>=(strpos($this->get( 'seo', 'description' ),' ')))
            $descr.=iconv_substr($this->get( 'seo', 'description' ), 0, $descrln, 'utf-8' );
        if ( $echo ) {
            echo "<title>".sprintf($format,$title)."</title>\r\n";
        } else {
            return sprintf($format,$title);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: interesting, if you right click the page to view source are you getting anything?  If you open the browsers console log, is it reporting any errors?

Comment: When I remove the two lines it fixes the tag issue and the site works correctly on the front end. The only issue is that when I update a post or page i get a white screen when logged into the admin. The updates are saved, but I have to go back to the main admin view to proceed.

Comment: what is your wordpress version and what theme are you using, default or an add-on?

Comment: Version 3.8.1 and the theme is SportsBlog from smthemes.com

Comment: Anybody have any ideas?